# Yet another issue with Rails and Exchange server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, smtp, exchange-server

i trying to get work Rails with Exchange server 2007. I trying to use difference auth methods with it: none, plain, ntlm, login. But none of them does not work and i see exceptions like this for every auth method:

```
504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type
```

After long googling i try to use telnet to watch what auth methods supported:

```
ehlo
...
250-AUTH
250-STARTTLS
...
```

250-AUTH without any params, but in any manuals in internet this line usually looks like 250-AUTH NTLM LOGIN.

What auth method i should use with this server or i must to reconfigure the exchange?

Comment: have you tried `authentication: none` as an option?

Comment: No, it means that server work at all without any authentication?

Comment: Thank you, `authentication: none` works for me

Answer (score 0):

Some mails servers (both incoming and outgoing) require encryption before they allow authentication.

Judging by the presence of STARTTLS, you are currently connected to port 25 or 587 without encryption.

Try to switch this connection into TLS mode by using the STARTTLS command and promoting your current plain socket to an SSL one. Then repeat EHLO and there should be some auth capabilities listed (e.g. "250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN").